# registering a function in a list as it is being defined

Tags: lisp

I am trying to make a list of callback functions, which could look like this:

```
(("command1" . 'callback1)
 ("command2" . 'callback2)
  etc)
```

I'd like it if I could could do something like:

```
(define-callback callback1 "command1" args
  (whatever the function does))
```

Rather than

```
(defun callback1 (args)
  (whatever the function does))

(add-to-list 'callback-info ("command1" . 'callback1))
```

Is there a convenient way of doing this, e.g., with macros?

Comment: Quoted symbols in data lists/conses don't make much sense. `(foo  'bar)` <- why would you quote `bar`? If lists are data, you might need to quote the list, but not it contents, to prevent evaluation.

Comment: Yeah, the quote symbol should go outside the whole list; the list isn't actually going to appear in the source code, though.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good example of a place where it's nice to use a two-layered approach, with an explicit function-based layer, and then a prettier macro layer on top of that.

Note the following assumes Common Lisp: it looks just possible from your question that you are asking about elisp, in which case something like this can be made to work but it's all much more painful.

First of all, we'll keep callbacks in an alist called `*callbacks*`:

```
(defvar *callbacks* '())
```

Here's a function which clears the alist of callbacks

```
(defun initialize-callbacks ()
  (setf *callbacks* '())
  (values)
```

Here is the function that installs a callback.  It does this by searching the list to see if there is a callback with the given name, and if there is then replacing it, and otherwise installing a new one.  Like all the functions in the functional layer lets us specify the test function which will let us know if two callback names are the same: by default this is `#'eql` which will work for symbols and numbers, but not for strings.  Symbols are probably a better choice for the names of callbacks than strings, but we'll cope with that below.

```
(defun install-callback (name function &key (test #'eql))
  (let ((found (assoc name *callbacks* :test test)))
    (if found
        (setf (cdr found) function)
      (push (cons name function) *callbacks*)))
  name)
```

Here is a function to find a callback, returning the function object, or `nil` if there is no callback with that name.

```
(defun find-callback (name &key (test #'eql))
  (cdr (assoc name *callbacks* :test test)))
```

And a function to remove a named callback.  This doesn't tell you if it did anything: perhaps it should.

```
(defun remove-callback (name &key (test #'eql))
  (setf *callbacks* (delete name *callbacks* :key #'car :test test))
  name)
```

Now comes the macro layer.  The syntax of this is going to be `(define-callback name arguments ...)`, so it looks a bit like a function definition.

There are three things to know about this macro.

1. It is a bit clever: because you can know at macro-expansion time what sort of thing the name of the callback is, you can decide then and there what test to use when installing the callback, and it does this.  If the name is a symbol it also wraps a `block` named by the symbol around the body of the function definition, so it smells a bit more like a function defined by `defun`: in particular you can use `return-from` in the body.  It does not do this if the name is not a symbol.
2. It is not quite clever enough: in particular it does not deal with docstrings in any useful way (it ought to pull them out of the block I think).  I am not sure this matters.
3. The switch to decide the test uses expressions like `'#'eql` which reads as `(quote (function eql))`: that is to avoid wiring in functions into the expansion because functions are not externalisable objects in CL.  However I am not sure I have got this right: I think what is there is *safe* but it may not be needed.

So, here it is

```
(defmacro define-callback (name arguments &body body)
  `(install-callback ',name
                     ,(if (symbolp name)
                          `(lambda ,arguments
                             (block ,name
                               ,@body))
                        `(lambda ,arguments
                           ,@body))
                     :test ,(typecase name
                              (string '#'string=)
                              (symbol '#'eql)
                              (number '#'=)
                              (t '#'equal))))
```

And finally here are two different callbacks being defined:

```
(define-callback "foo" (x)
  (+ x 3))

(define-callback foo (x)
  (return-from foo (+ x 1)))
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I kinda knew a two-layered approach would be best. In the end, I came down to something like:

(I can't work out how to get backquotes into comments, see below)

Answer (score 1):

These lists are called *assoc lists* in Lisp.

```
CL-USER 120 > (defvar *foo* '(("c1" . c1) ("c2" . c2)))
*FOO*

CL-USER 121 > (setf *foo* (acons "c0" `c1 *foo*))
(("c0" . C1) ("c1" . C1) ("c2" . C2))

CL-USER 122 > (assoc "c1" *foo* :test #'equal)
("c1" . C1)
```

You can write macros for that, but why? Macros are advanced Lisp and you might want to get the basics right, first.

Some issues with you example you might want to check out:

- what are assoc lists?
- what are useful key types in assoc lists?
- why you don't need to quote symbols in data lists
- variables are not quoted
- data lists need to be quoted

You can just as easy create such lists for callbacks without macros. We can imagine a function `create-callback`, which would be used like this:

```
(create-callback 'callback1 "command1"
   (lambda (arg)
     (whatever the function does)))
```

Now, why would you use a macro instead of a plain function?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, assisted by the responders above, I got it down to something like:

```
(defmacro mk-make-command (name &rest body)
  (let ((func-sym (intern (format "mk-cmd-%s" name))))
    (mk-register-command name func-sym)
    `(defun ,func-sym (args &rest rest)
       (progn
         ,@body))))
```